# $_FILES and form enctype

Tags: php, arrays, forms

If a form has not file element and enctype="multipart/form-data" properties is setted, `$_FILES` always is setted as an empty array, right? I have to know for handling upload and doing nothing about upload. How can I distinguish `$_FILES['name']['error'] > 0`  or `isset($_FILES[0])` ?

If form has file element, `$_FILES['name']['error'] > 0`

If form hasn't file element, `isset($_FILES[0])`

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question?

Comment: That's the point. How can I know if form has file element?

Comment: or just `if(count($_FILES) > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three pages.

- page 1: has a form, no enctype, no file input
- page 2: has a form, no enctype, a file input
- page 3: has a form, proper enctype, a file input

Have each form `print_r($_FILES, $_POST)` below the `<form>` html.

Test.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how can you test to see if form has the upload field not filled in?

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php